# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.vertx.core.spi.metrics.Pool Metrics

Tags: java, vert.x

this is my code  `Vertx.vertx(new VertxOptions().setMetricsOptions(new DropwizardMetricsOptions().setEnabled(true)));`
when i run it ,then error java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.vertx.core.spi.metrics.Pool Metrics

Comment: Your code excerpt is too small to understand the issue, please show everything (including imports).

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you included the `vertx-dropwizard-metrics` dependency in your build automation tool (maven/gradle/...), according to this documentation : https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-dropwizard-metrics/java/

For example, using maven (in your `pom.xml`):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.vertx</groupId>
    <artifactId>vertx-dropwizard-metrics</artifactId>
    <version>${vertx.version}</version>
</dependency>
```